# How to log heap memory usage in JRuby?

Tags: jruby

To monitor memory usage in the course of a long running JRuby application, I would like to log at certain crucial points the heap memory currently in use. How can I do it?

The closest I found, is `GC.stat[:used]`, but was does the number stored in this slot really mean? I don't think it denotes the heap memory in bytes, because in my example this is ridiculously high (11000000000.0), and it is a fractional number, which does not make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following solution:

```
require 'java'
import java.lang.management.ManagementFactory
mbean = ManagementFactory.getMemoryMXBean
current_heap_in_bytes = mbean.getHeapMemoryUsage.used
```

This is documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/management/ManagementFactory.html) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/management/MemoryUsage.html).

Of course, if someone knows a simpler way to do  it, I would gladly accept such an alternative as answer.